# Boost MSM processing event not by direct call

Tags: boost, state-machine

This question is due to the following core dump we had.

```
#0  0x000056171395d2b0 in std::_Vector_base<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_deallocate (this=<optimized out>, __n=<optimized out>, __p=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:300
#1  std::_Vector_base<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::~_Vector_base (this=<optimized out>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:285
#2  std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::~vector (this=<optimized out>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:570
#3  ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlImpl::StoreOudpFlowStatsData (this=0x56171bdbf200, flowCcfCounters=...) at ../../src/mac-domain/oudp/UsChanOudpCtrl.cpp:962
#4  0x0000561713985365 in ccap::CyclingSm_::GettingDpOudpStats::on_exit<boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::CyclingSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_> > (this=this@entry=0x56171bdbf3b0, rEvent=..., rFsm=...) at /usr/include/nsg-logctl/1.4/nsg-logctl/foundation/LoggerService.hpp:112
#5  0x00005617139857fe in boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::CyclingSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::execute_exit<ccap::CyclingSm_::GettingDpOudpStats, ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp, boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::CyclingSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_> > (fsm=..., evt=..., astate=...) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:2765
#6  boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::CyclingSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::_row_<boost::msm::front::Row<ccap::CyclingSm_::GettingDpOudpStats, ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp, ccap::CyclingSm_::PseudoCycleExit, boost::msm::front::none, boost::msm::front::none> >::execute (fsm=..., 
    region_index=<optimized out>, state=<optimized out>, evt=...) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:664
#7  0x000056171397923c in boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::CyclingSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::region_processing_helper<ccap::CyclingSm_, void>::process<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (this=<synthetic pointer>, this=<synthetic pointer>, evt=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:2021
#8  boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::CyclingSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::do_process_event<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=false, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf310) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:2026
#9  boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::CyclingSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::do_process_helper<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp, ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=false, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf310) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1768
#10 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::CyclingSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::process_event_internal<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=false, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf310) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1997
#11 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::CyclingSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::process_event_internal<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=false, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf310) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1976
#12 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::OperationalSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::frow<boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::CyclingSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>, ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp>::execute (fsm=..., 
    region_index=0, evt=...) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1024
#13 0x000056171397058c in boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::OperationalSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::region_processing_helper<ccap::OperationalSm_, void>::process<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (this=<synthetic pointer>, this=<synthetic pointer>, evt=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:2021
#14 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::OperationalSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::do_process_event<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=false, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf290) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:2026
#15 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::OperationalSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::do_process_helper<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp, ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=false, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf290) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1768
#16 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::OperationalSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::process_event_internal<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=false, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf290) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1997
#17 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::OperationalSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::process_event_internal<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=false, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf290) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1976
#18 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::frow<boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::OperationalSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>, ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp>::execute (fsm=..., 
    region_index=0, evt=...) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1024
#19 0x0000561713969c55 in boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::region_processing_helper<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, void>::process<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (this=<synthetic pointer>, this=<synthetic pointer>, evt=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:2021
#20 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::do_process_event<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=true, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf210) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:2026
#21 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::do_process_helper<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp, ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=true, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf210) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1768
#22 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::process_event_internal<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=true, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf210) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1997
#23 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::process_event_internal<ccap::EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp> (is_direct_call=true, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf210) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1976
#24 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::process_event<ccap::EventSe--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
\ndOudpFlowStatsRsp> (this=0x56171bdbf210, evt=...) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1264
#25 0x0000561713967e96 in boost::function0<boost::msm::back::HandledEnum>::operator() (this=0x7f1752808730) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:682
#26 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::process_message_queue<boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_> > (this=this@entry=0x56171bdbf210)
    at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:2697
#27 0x000056171395fca6 in boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::do_post_msg_queue_helper (this=0x56171bdbf210) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1848
#28 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::process_event_internal<ccap::EventSendSchedOudpGrantsInfoRsp> (is_direct_call=true, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf210) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:2013
#29 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::process_event_internal<ccap::EventSendSchedOudpGrantsInfoRsp> (is_direct_call=true, evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf210) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1976
#30 boost::msm::back::state_machine<ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlSm_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::process_event<ccap::EventSendSchedOudpGrantsInfoRsp> (evt=..., this=0x56171bdbf210) at /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:1264
#31 ccap::UsChanOudpCtrlImpl::ProcessEvent<ccap::EventSendSchedOudpGrantsInfoRsp> (rEvent=..., this=0x56171bdbf200) at ../../src/mac-domain/oudp/UsChanOudpCtrl.cpp:591


#32 ccap::UsChanOudpCtrl::ProcEventSendSchedOudpGrantsInfoRsp (this=<optimized out>, grantsInfo=..., rc=rc@entry=true) at ../../src/mac-domain/oudp/UsChanOudpCtrl.cpp:1336
^C#33 0x0000561713951e05 in ccap::MdOudpManager::ProcEventSendSchedOudpGrantsInfoRsp (this=0x561718f8bb30, channelId=44 ',', Python Exception <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'> <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>: 
grantsInfo=..., rc=<optimized out>)
```

We saw in this core dump that for some reason there is event which is not executed immediately (`is_direct_call=false`) while we are not deferring it.
Our assumption is that if we asking to process an event while processing another event the SM is not handling the event immidately but putting it in some "deferred event queue" and processing it later (when?).

This is the transition table for reference:

```
struct transition_table : mpl::vector<
//         Start                            Event                            Next                               Action                                          Guard
//        +-------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------+
msmf::Row<FillingCmDetails,                 EventSendFillCmOudpDetailsRsp,    SendingSchedOudpGrants,           ActionFillCmOudpDetails,                        msmf::none>,
msmf::Row<SendingSchedOudpGrants,           EventSendSchedOudpGrantsRsp,      GettingSchedOudpGrantsInfo,       ActionStoreSchedOudpGrantsReqData,              msmf::none>,
msmf::Row<GettingSchedOudpGrantsInfo,       EventSendSchedOudpGrantsInfoRsp,  PseudoCycleExit,                  ActionStoreOudpGrantsInfoData,                  msmf::none>,
msmf::Row<GettingSchedOudpGrantsInfo,       EventSendSchedOudpGrantsInfoRsp,  GettingDpOudpStats,               ActionStoreOudpGrantsInfoData,                  GuardOudpStatsTimerExpired>,
msmf::Row<GettingDpOudpStats,               EventSendOudpFlowStatsRsp,        PseudoCycleExit,                  msmf::none,                                     msmf::none >

>, OBJECTS_COUNTER(transition_table) {};
```

Is this an expected behavior and in what cases we expect to see this flag marked as false (and event not processed immediately)?